# PostgreSQL to Java Data Types (Grails)

Tags: postgresql, grails, types

I have the following (Grails) domain object:

```
class Country {

Integer id
char country_abbr
String country_name

static mapping = {
    version false
    id name: 'id'
    table 'country'
    id generator:'identity', column:'id'
}

static constraints = {
}}
```

The **'country_abbr'** field within the **'country table'** has type: **character(2)**. However, whenever I am setting the domain object's data type (for **'country_abbr'**) to **String**, initialization is failing with the following exception

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in mydb.country for column country_abbr. Found: bpchar, expected: varchar(255)
```

On the other hand, leaving this type as a Java **char** would only retrieve the first character. Any ideas how may I map to this type? Also, what is bpchar exactly?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to add the id attribute, this is made automatic by Grails. Also, the convention is to use camelcase in your attributes, Grails will handle the conversion to underscores for retrieving data. String countryName will be translated to country_name in querys.

Comment: [It seems a problem of Hibernate mapping](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/33043-mapping-error-with-postgres). Could you try char[] for countryAbbr?

Comment: @SérgioMichels It still fails with char[]; thanks for the other tips :)

Comment: Can you try this approach: http://cedar715.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-wrong-column-type-found-char-expected-varchar2255/? Add to your mapping: `country_abbr columnDefinition: 'char'`

Comment: @SérgioMichels The schema validation is passing using the '@Column' annotation, however the execution is ending up in a stack overflow when trying to retrieve that field's value.

Comment: With the Grails way you don't need the @Column annotation. Just use as I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make this question answered. The solution is to change the country_abbr mapping:

```
country_abbr columnDefinition: 'char'
```

Reference [here](http://cedar715.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-wrong-column-type-found-char-expected-varchar2255/).